# Do you need to de-allocate an array of primitives?

Tags: c++, memory-management

If I have an array of a primitive type for example: int A[] = new int[10];
Would it create a memory leak if not freed?

This is a question that popped into my head recently. I'm sure I learned it in school, but it's been such a long time since I've used C/C++ I can't remember exactly. As it was, creating any object with "new" puts that object on the heap which must be freed/destroyed at some point. I remember doing this with arrays of objects and it would make sense to do so, but I don't ever remember needing to free an array of int or String. So is this case with primitive arrays as well?

thanks

Will

Comment: `int A[] = new int[10];` is an error.  If you meant `int *A = new int[10];` then you must call `delete` later. But if you meant `int A[10];` then no delete is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allocate something with `new`, and it isn't handed off to a smart-pointer or something for management, you have to `delete` it. It doesn't matter whether it's an object or a primitive type.

Be careful with the word "free" here. You shouldn't use the function `free` on anything that was allocated with `new`. Also make sure you understand the difference between `delete` and `delete[]`.

Even better, use `std::vector` instead of dynamic arrays and you don't have to worry about deleting anything.